# Lotus Notes 8.5 prompts me for a password after I come back from being idle. It also sets my Sametime to 'Do Not Disturb'

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-sametime

I will come back to my computer after being away, and see that I can't use Lotus Notes until I input my password again.  I can't cancel out of it, or click on any window behind the password prompt until I have input it. My Sametime Status is "Do Not Disturb" until I enter the password and then it returns to 'Available'.  The status is real -- I have had comments from others who notice my status.

This problem went away last time I changed my password two weeks ago, or so. Then last night it started again.

Answer (score 4):

Just go to `File - Security - User Security`. Enter your password and remove the checkmark for `Automatically lock my Notes ID after`in the `Logout Settings` sections in `Security Basics`- Tab.

If you can't remove this setting, then there is a policy that sets this value and you have to ask your administrator to remove it.

To make sametime NOT reflect your status, open `File - Preferences` and Edit the settings found under `Sametime - Auto-Status Changes`